# How do I pretty-print HTML with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, pretty-print

I wrote a web crawler in Ruby and I'm using `Nokogiri::HTML` to parse the page. I need to print the page out and while messing around in IRB I noticed a `pretty_print` method. However it takes a parameter and I can't figure out what it wants.

My crawler is caching the HTML of the webpages and writing it to files on my local machine. I would like to "pretty print" the HTML so that it looks nice and properly formatted when I do so.

Comment: what are you wanting to print? the html content (tags and all) or select items? 

there are different methods for each and a clarification would really help with for an answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By "pretty printing" of HTML page I presume you meant that you want to reformat the HTML structure with proper indentation. Nokogiri doesn't support this; the `pretty_print` method is for the "pp" library and the output is useful for debugging only.

There are several projects that understand HTML well enough to be able to reformat it without destroying whitespace that is actually significant (the famous one is [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)), but by Googling I've found this post titled ["Pretty printing XHTML with Nokogiri and XSLT"](http://emmanueloga.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/pretty-printing-xhtml-with-nokogiri-and-xslt/).

It comes down to this:

```
xsl = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.open("pretty_print.xsl"))
html = Nokogiri(File.open("source.html"))
puts xsl.apply_to(html).to_s
```

It requires you, of course, to download the linked XSL file to your filesystem. I've tried it very quickly on my machine and it works like a charm.

Comment: FWIW the linked stylesheet can result in spaces being added to rendered HTML (e.g. `<p><span>pre</span>fix</p>` becomes "pre fix").

Answer (score 86):

The answer by @mislav is somewhat wrong. Nokogiri does support pretty-printing *if* you:

- Parse the document as XML
- Instruct Nokogiri to ignore whitespace-only nodes ("blanks") during parsing
- Use `to_xhtml` or `to_xml` to specify [pretty-printing parameters](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#write_to-instance_method)

In action:

```ruby
html = '<section>
<h1>Main Section 1</h1><p>Intro</p>
<section>
<h2>Subhead 1.1</h2><p>Meat</p><p>MOAR MEAT</p>
</section><section>
<h2>Subhead 1.2</h2><p>Meat</p>
</section></section>'

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(html,&:noblanks)
puts doc
#=> <section>
#=>   <h1>Main Section 1</h1>
#=>   <p>Intro</p>
#=>   <section>
#=>     <h2>Subhead 1.1</h2>
#=>     <p>Meat</p>
#=>     <p>MOAR MEAT</p>
#=>   </section>
#=>   <section>
#=>     <h2>Subhead 1.2</h2>
#=>     <p>Meat</p>
#=>   </section>
#=> </section>

puts doc.to_xhtml( indent:3, indent_text:"." )
#=> <section>
#=> ...<h1>Main Section 1</h1>
#=> ...<p>Intro</p>
#=> ...<section>
#=> ......<h2>Subhead 1.1</h2>
#=> ......<p>Meat</p>
#=> ......<p>MOAR MEAT</p>
#=> ...</section>
#=> ...<section>
#=> ......<h2>Subhead 1.2</h2>
#=> ......<p>Meat</p>
#=> ...</section>
#=> </section>
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't split chain of tags into several lines, but writes them one after another. Such problem appears in originally-one-tag-per-line document after the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696537 – after that code tags somehow are joining to one chain, making this to_xhtml a bit useless (

Comment: @Nakilon Did you parse the XML using the &:noblanks option?

Comment: yep, http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tKSSVjaG – remove `if false` to see, how `change_language` urls are joining. (smth wrong with my browser or SO, can't write ur username with @, it's just disappearing, lol)

Comment: @Nakilon Looks fine to me; what am I missing? (Since I'm the author of the item you're commenting on the @ is unnecessary for notification, so SO tries to be helpful by not letting you add it.)

Comment: This `<li><ul><li><a href="/?change_language=fr">Fran&#xE7;ais</a></li><li><a href="/?change_language=nl">Nederlands</a></li><li><a href=` was joined into one line after the tag stripping, while it was on several lines before. So currently I have to use Julien's REXML (pretty-printing) in addition to Nokogiri (stripping), but in that way I parse the document twice, which isn't looking cool.

Comment: @Nakilon You should ask this as a new question with a simple repro case (including simple XML).

Comment: Could you please point me to the link/source where you found `&:noblanks` in the official doc ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit That is Ruby shortcut for `Nokogiri.XML(…){|config| config.noblanks }`. The `Nokogiri.XML()` method is documented as a shortcut for [`Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-c-parse). The block passed to the method is a shorthand for passing [parse options](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions.html).

Comment: I am applying the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957190/how-to-wrap-nokogiri-nodeset-in-one-span) not happening.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont wrap long lines into multiple ones.

Comment: @DavidG You can do that yourself rather easily, with matching indentation, even. `wrapped = result.gsub(/^([ \t]*)(.{70,})(.+)/,'\1\2\n\1\3')`

Comment: i tried a lot, the key is `&:noblanks` at the reading. saved my day!

Comment: I get a huge torrent of nonsense full of cucumber pollution lasting about a minute of high-speed scrolling, when I type puts Nokogiri::XML('', &:noblanks) at the Pry prompt. Kernel.puts works better. I hate Ruby.

Comment: @android.weasel and what happens when you call `to_xhtml` on the document? And, you realize that you're parsing an empty string as a document? What do you hope to have happen? Post as your own question of you cannot figure it out, not as a complaint comment on another answer.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
 pretty_html = Nokogiri::HTML(html).to_xhtml(indent: 3)
```

I tried the REXML version above, but it corrupted some of my documents.  And I hate to bring xslt into a new project.  Both feel antiquated.  :)

Comment: This is good, but adds ```<body>``` and ```<html>``` tags if those are missing. In my case I don't need them at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can try REXML:

```
require "rexml/document"

doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
doc.write($stdout, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to add a `print` method onto the actual `Nokogiri` objects. After you run the code in the snippet below, you should just be able to write `node.print`, and it'll pretty print the contents. No xslt required :-)

```
Nokogiri::XML::Node.class_eval do
  # Print every Node by default (will be overridden by CharacterData)
  define_method :should_print? do
    true
  end

  # Duplicate this node, replace the contents of the duplicated node with a
  # newline. With this content substitution, the #to_s method conveniently
  # returns a string with the opening tag (e.g. `<a href="foo">`) on the first
  # line and the closing tag on the second (e.g. `</a>`, provided that the
  # current node is not a self-closing tag).
  #
  # Now, print the open tag preceded by the correct amount of indentation, then
  # recursively print this node's children (with extra indentation), and then
  # print the close tag (if there is a closing tag)
  define_method :print do |indent=0|
    duplicate = self.dup
    duplicate.content = "\n"
    open_tag, close_tag = duplicate.to_s.split("\n")

    puts (" " * indent) + open_tag
    self.children.select(&:should_print?).each { |child| child.print(indent + 2) }
    puts (" " * indent) + close_tag if close_tag
  end
end

Nokogiri::XML::CharacterData.class_eval do
  # Only print CharacterData if there's non-whitespace content
  define_method :should_print? do
    content =~ /\S+/
  end

  # Replace all consecutive whitespace characters by a single space; precede the
  # outut by a certain amount of indentation; print this text.
  define_method :print do |indent=0|
    puts (" " * indent) + to_s.strip.sub(/\s+/, ' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have an example of it being used? I try this and get "TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String" so perhaps I'm calling it on the wrong object.

Comment: A few more experiments and I got this to work: `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_source);  doc.elements.each {|elem| elem.print }`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler and works well

```
puts Nokogiri::HTML(File.read('terms.fr.html')).to_xhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am extremely late to answer this question, but still, I'll leave the answer. I tried all the above steps and it does work to an extent.

`Nokogiri` does format the `HTML` but does not care about the closing or the opening tag, hence pretty format is out of the picture.

I found a gem called [htmlbeautifier](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier) that works like a charm. I hope other people who are still searching for the answer will find this valuable.

Answer (score -6):

why don't you try the `pp` method?

```
require 'pp'
pp some_var
```

Comment: While Nokogiri implements methods to aid "pretty printing", the output is intended for developers only. It seems to me that Jarsen wants to display pretty-printed HTML source.