# Strip all tbody tags without destroying their children

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This Ruby code using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org)

```
doc.xpath("//tbody").remove
```

removes the children of the `<tbody>` (as well as the `<tbody>` themselves). I only want to remove all `<tbody>` tags from the document, leaving their children in place. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA)
html.xpath('//table/tbody').each do |tbody|
  tbody.children.each do |child|
    child.parent = tbody.parent
  end
  tbody.remove
end

puts html.xpath('//table').to_s

__END__
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"><tbody>
<tr><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data3</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

prints

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 for a working answer. See my answer for a simpler way to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace each `tbody` with its children? Then that's all you need to say:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
html = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(DATA.read)
html.css('tbody').each{ |tbody| tbody.replace tbody.children }
puts html

__END__
<table><tbody>
  <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data2</td></tr>
</tbody><tbody>
  <tr><td>Data3</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Producing:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data3</td></tr>
</table>
```