# How to wrap Nokogiri nodeset in ONE span

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

So my goal is to wrap all paragraphs after the initial paragraph within a span. I'm trying to figure out how to wrap a nodeset within a single span and .wrap() wraps each node in its own span. As in want:

```html
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
```

To become:

```html
<p>First</p>
<span>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
</span>
```

Any sample code to help? Thanks!

Comment: If this is HTML, note that a `p` inside a `span` isn’t valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc =  Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<-html)
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
html

nodeset = doc.css("p")
new_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('span',doc)
new_node << nodeset[1..-1]
nodeset.first.after(new_node)
puts doc.to_html
# >> <p>First</p><span><p>Second</p>
# >> <p>Third</p></span>
# >>
```

Comment: Ps: use a Fragment instead of a Document.

Comment: @Phrogz Yeah.. that was a typo. But how to do pretty print ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

paragraphs = doc.search('p')[1..-1].unlink 
doc.at('p').after('<span>')
doc.at('span').add_child(paragraphs)
puts doc.to_html
```

Which results in HTML looking like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>First</p>
<span><p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p></span>

</body></html>
```

To give you an idea what's happening, here's a more verbose output showing intermediate changes to the `doc`:

```
paragraphs = doc.search('p')[1..-1].unlink 
paragraphs.to_html 
# => "<p>Second</p><p>Third</p>"
doc.at('p').after('<span>')
doc.to_html 
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<p>First</p>\n<span></span>\n\n</body></html>\n"
doc.at('span').add_child(paragraphs)
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<p>First</p>\n<span><p>Second</p>\n<p>Third</p></span>\n\n</body></html>\n"
```

Looking at the initial HTML, I'm not sure the question asked is going to work well for normal, everyday HTML, however, if you are absolutely sure it'll never change from the

```
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

layout then you should be OK. Any answer based on the initial, sample, HTML, will blow up miserably if the HTML really is something like:

```
<div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
...
<div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```